# Creating file with filename containing date crashes the app

Tags: android, date, time, sdk, crash

I seem to have a problem with some phones, that the app crashes when using the getDate()
in a file name saved to the SD Card.

This is my function:

```
public static String getDate() {

String date;
  Time now = new Time();
  now.setToNow();

date = now.format("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S");

return date;

}
```

Any idea why this could be?
If I Toast() the getDate() function on the phone, it doesn't crash, but if used with a File name, it crashes every time.

Comment: post that code that u have written for filename and show logcat values.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can't use ":" in filenames. Try "%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S"

Comment: Dimmerg, You're right. Replacing ":" did the trick :) Thanks!